# Getting this error while running ionic code in Android studio - AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource identifier found for attribute

Tags: android-studio, build, ionic2, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am working with Ionic project and I need to run this project with my android studio. I have resolved all the issues which are coming in the gradle file but when I am trying to run the code getting below error

**error -** No resource identifier found for attribute 'appComponentFactory' in package 'android'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0eKi.png)
above image is when I have fixed all the issue

but getting below error on runtime

```
**AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource identifier found for attribute \u0027appComponentFactory\u0027 in package \u0027android\u0027","sources":[{"file":"/Users/naya-pc/Documents/Ionic/xyz/platforms/android/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml","position":{"startLine":57}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
/Users/naya-pc/Documents/Ionic/xyz/platforms/android/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:58: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'appComponentFactory' in package 'android'
:processDebugResources FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt**
```

Also, I have tried the basic technique to resolve this type of issue 
 1. clean project 
 2. rebuild project
 3. invalidate the cache and restart 
but still getting the same issue.

I have changed almost every gradle file with the new one and old one but getting the same issue below are my gradle and they are working gradle.

```
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0"
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0"

compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+"
compile "com.google.gms:google-services:+"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:+"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:+"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:+"

compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:15.0.1"
```

Please help me if you have any solution for this issue.